# Passing array contents into function not working correctly

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

When trying to pass an array into a function it doesn't do anything at all. My code is below

main.py

```
import items
import npcs.py

def pickup(item):
    global player_weight_max,player_weight,player_inv
    #Calculates if item's weight will make player_weight go over player_weight_max
    if player_weight + item[5] <= player_weight_max:
        player_inv.append(item)
        player_weight = player_weight + item[5]
    else:
        print("You're not able to carry this item.")

def npc(npc):
    #Prints NPC speech
    if npc[2] != None:
        print("".join(npc[1]) + ": " + "".join(npc[2]))
    else:
        pass
    for function in npc[3]:
        if function[0] == 'pickup':
            pickup(function[1])
        if function[0] == 'battle':
            battle(function[1])
```

npcs.py

```
import items

#art,name,speech,functions
test_guy = [["art"],["name"],["speech"],[
        [['pickup'],[items.armour[0]],
        [['pickup'],[items.armour[1]],
    ]
]
```

items.py

```
armour = [
    [str(""),str("Tin Helmet"),int(1),int(20),str("head"),int(2),int(0),int(2)],
    [str(""),str("Tin Chestplate"),int(1),int(20),str("torso"),int(0),int(1),int(2)],
    [str(""),str("Tin Pants"),int(1),int(20),str("legs"),int(3),int(0),int(2)],
    [str(""),str("Tin Boots"),int(1),int(20),str("feet"),int(2),int(0),int(2)],
]
```

Why is pickup() not appending the information obtained from items.py

I have already verified pickup() works when doing pickup(items.armour[0]) which should just be passing the array at that location into pickup(), why can the same not be done with the information contained in test_guy[3][0] and test_guy[3][1]?

updated the code as follows:

```
def npc(npc):
    #Prints NPC speech
    if npc[2] != None:
        print("".join(npc[1]) + ": " + "".join(npc[2]))
    else:
        pass
    for function in npc[3]:
        print(function[1][0])
        if function[0][0] == 'pickup':
            pickup(function[1][0])
        if function[0][0] == 'battle':
            battle(function[1][0])
```

upon running:

```
npc(npcs.test_guy)
print(player_inv)
```

the output is now correct:

```
name: speech
['', 'Tin Helmet', 1, 20, 'head', 2, 0, 2]
['', 'Tin Chestplate', 1, 20, 'torso', 0, 1, 2]
[['', 'Tin Helmet', 1, 20, 'head', 2, 0, 2], ['', 'Tin Chestplate', 1, 20, 'torso', 0, 1, 2]]
```

Thank you!

(Yes I know this is not the most efficient way to do things, I'm still learning and just trying to get things working for now)

Comment: I'm guessing you're getting lots of other errors (i.e with imports) before even looking at why the pickup function isn't referencing items at all.

Comment: imports are fine, everything else is functional except for this.

Comment: None of this code actually calls `pickup().`  Show us an actual call to `pickup()`, explain what you want it to do, and explain why the results aren't what you want.

Comment: the `npc` calls `pickup` but nothing calls the `npc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst avoiding the unnecessary complexity of this code..

Your items are within another array so `item[0]` will never equal `pickup/battle` and equally, `item[1]` will never be the item, it will be an array with an item.

So first fix the missing brackets of your functions part of `test_guy`, and then reference the functions inner array first

`item[0][0]` and `item[0][1]`

Comment: Works good, what is a more efficient way of accomplishing this? I don't need a full answer, just point me in the right direction.

Comment: @MaximilianPatterson - Classes